# Тип предложения - "... , что для Нью-Йорка было бы невообразимо"?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем является выделенный момент синтаксически?

> *Все сидели дома, никуда не выходили, **что для Нью-Йорка было бы
>   невообразимо.***

Я сказала бы какая-то пояснительная конструкция (но мои знания очень маленькие про присоединительные конструкции). Русская девочка говорит, что это относительное предложение (хотя я не вижу слово, к которому оно относилось бы).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Все сидели дома, никуда не выходили, **что для Нью-Йорка было бы невообразимо**.*
>
> ...чем является выделенный момент синтаксически?

По [**Литневской**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#42114)  —  ***придаточное присоединительное***.

> **Сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными присоединительными**
>
> В русском языке представлен еще один тип придаточных предложений, не
>   нашедший отражения ни в одном из учебных комплексов. Это **придаточные
>   присоединительные**. Их особенность заключается в том, что они не
>   эквивалентны ни одному из членов предложения, к ним не может быть
>   поставлен вопрос от главной части, что является причиной их выделения
>   в отдельную группу.
>
> Средства связи придаточной части с главной в этом типе придаточного —
>   **союзные слова** *что* (в форме любого падежа с предлогом или без него), *отчего, почему, зачем*, вмещающие в себя содержание главной
>   части; средства связи в ПП присоединительных могут быть заменены для
>   диагностики на местоимение *это*:
>
> *И каждый раз в течение семи лет старик хватался за сердце, **что** (= это) очень всех потешало* (И. Ильф и Е. Петров) — средство связи —
>   союзное слово *что*, являющееся подлежащим.
>
> *Я здоров, **чего** (= этого) и вам желаю* — средство связи — союзное слово *чего*, являющееся дополнением.
>
> *Он опаздывал, **отчего** (= от этого) мы не могли начать представление вовремя* — средство связи — союзное слово *отчего*,
>   являющееся обстоятельством.

По [**"Грамматике-80"**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2918-2946.html)  — ***придаточное распространительно-изъяснительное*** (более подробно см. [**§ 2918—2923**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2918-2946.html)).

Comment: большое спасибо Вам!